# Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)] with root cause in Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot

i have an entity which has a one to many relationship with another entity

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "npm_cores")
public class NPMCore implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public List<NPMFinition> getNpmFinitions() {
        return npmFinitions;
    }

    public void setNpmFinitions(List<NPMFinition> npmFinitions) {
        this.npmFinitions = npmFinitions;
    }
}
```

This is NPMFinition

```
public class NPMFinition implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "npm_core_id")
    private NPMCore NPMCore;

}
```

i added a GET endpoint on this model

```
    @GetMapping("")
    private ResponseEntity<List<NPMCore>> getAllNpmCores()
    {
        List<NPMCore> npmCores = npmCoreService.getAllNpmCores();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(npmCores , HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

i got this error

> Could not write JSON: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError)] with root cause

i get this error whenever i request the endpoint does someone know how to solve this issue ?

Comment: can you share `NPMFinition` class definition ?

Comment: I believe that you need to annotate NPMCore in NPMFinition with @JsonIgnore, but I am not sure without looking at full definition of these classes

Comment: Stop using your Entities at REST API Level. Learn about proper 3tier architecture

Comment: @jens why if we have dto are the sames as our entities ?

Comment: Because with the Entity annaotation you have a lot of other objects attached. Take a look at such objects in teh debugger.

Comment: i know that but it really depends on the context

Comment: i will add NPM Finition now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NPMCore` has a reference to `NPMFinition` and `NPMFinition` has a reference to `NPMCore` causing an infinite loop when trying to render to json which ultimately causes a `StackOverflowError`

```json
{   
   id: 1
   npmFinitions: [ {
      id: 2,
      npmCore: {
         id:1, 
         npmFinitions: [ {
            id: 2,
            npmCore: { ... }
         } ] 
      }
   } ]
}
```

You should add `@JsonIgnore` to one of the getters (or `@JsonIgnoreProperties` at the class level). See [Jackson Ignore Properties on Marshalling](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-ignore-properties-on-serialization)

Eg

```java
public class NPMFinition implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "npm_core_id")
    private NPMCore NPMCore;
}
```

Comment: it works, thanks for the explanation very coherent answer